# I'm pulling the style number for configurable products instead of the sku (simple) in my data array

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product, sku, items

For u2 it populates the style number and I'm trying to pull the sku/upc.

Here's what i have:

```
    if ($module === 'website_checkout' && $controller === 'onepage' && $action === 'success') {
        $order = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrder();
        if ($order->getId()) {
            $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            $itemIds = array();
            $itemNames = array();
            $itemPrices = array();
            $itemMargins = array();
            $itemTypes = array();
            $itemGenders = array();
            $itemSports = array();
            $itemCategoryIds = array();
            $itemCategoryNames = array();
            /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
            foreach ($items as $item) {

                // Get the parent item - it is NOT included in the quote due to
                // customizations made by the OrganicInternet module for simple
                // product pricing. So I had to come up with another way to get it.
                $options = $item->getProductOptions();
                $parent = $item->getProduct();
                if (array_key_exists('info_buyRequest', $options)) {
                    if (array_key_exists('cpid', $options['info_buyRequest'])) {
                        $parentId = $options['info_buyRequest']['cpid'];
                        $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('season')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('gender')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('sport')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $parentId)
                            ->getFirstItem();
                    }
                }

                $itemIds[] = $item->getSku();
                $itemNames[] = $parent->getName();
                $itemPrices[] = $item->getBasePrice() ?: 0;
                $itemMargins[] = $this->_calculateMargin($parent, null, $item);
                $itemTypes[] = $parent->getAttributeText('season');
                $itemGenders[] = $parent->getAttributeText('gender');
                $itemSports[] = $parent->getAttributeText('sport') ?: 'Other';
                $categories = $this->_getAllCategoryIdsAndNames($item->getProduct());
                $itemCategoryIds[] = $categories['id'];
                $itemCategoryNames[] = $categories['name'];
            }

            // # Products

            $data['u1'] = count($items);

            // Product(s) Ids
            $data['u2'] = $itemIds;
```

Output is like so:

```
<script>dataLayer = [{"u1":"2.0000","u16":"2","u14":"Product","u2":"A0141602","}];</script>
```

What have i done wrong? Why is it not pulling the actual sku but the style number???